# Low-contrast MediaStyle notifications on Marshmallow

Tags: android, colors, notifications

A non-custom notification built with `android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle` can appear in very low contrast on Android Marshmallow. (It's fine on Lollipop and Nougat.)

**Fig. 1.** On Marshmallow, from outside the app, its pull-down notification has light text on a dark background:
[image: dark pull-down MediaStyle notification on Marshmallow]

**Fig. 2.** When the app's Activity is running, it switches to non-`MediaStyle` to present alarm notifications without play/pause/stop controls, so they get the expected dark text on a light background:
[image: light heads-up notification on Marshmallow]

**Fig. 3.** On Marshmallow, outside the app the heads-up notification has very low contrast:
[image: low-contrast heads-up MediaStyle notification on Marshmallow]
*--> That's hard to read!*

**Fig. 4.** As an experiment, calling `NotificationCompat.Builder#setColor(0xb71c1c)` does indeed set the non-`MediaStyle` notification's accent color (compare with Fig. 2):
[image: light heads-up notification on Marshmallow with accent color]

**Fig. 5.** ... and on Marshmallow, it sets the background color of `MediaStyle` notifications:
[image: red background-colored pull-down MediaStyle notification on Marshmallow]
which is too much color and no doubt out of spec.

**Fig. 6.** As a test workaround, the app could call `setColor(0x9e9e9e)` (the standard accent color), which makes the heads-up notification more readable if out of spec:
[image: light-gray background-colored heads-up MediaStyle notification on Marshmallow]

**Fig. 7.** ... but it also makes the pull-down notification unusual and out of spec:
[image: light-gray background-colored pull-down MediaStyle notification on Marshmallow]

**Fig. 8.** ... and it looks worse in the large form:
[image: light-gray large format pull-down MediaStyle notification, showing color clash in context of other notifications]

*Q. Is there a workaround to make the heads-up `MediaStyle` notification more readable without messing up the pull-down `MediaStyle` notification?*

Obviously it'll be a Marshmallow-only workaround.

**Edit:** The bug is yet weirder. I tried to predict when it's likely to get a heads-up notification (that is, building a `MediaStyle` notification with `setSound()`) on Marshmallow, and call `setColor()` only in that case. If the new notification replaces a pull-down notification of the same ID, it inherits the background color from that one! I.e. the *previous* pull-down notification's `setColor()` sets this new heads-up notification's background color, while the later call to `setColor()` sets its accent color. If the new notification doesn't replace a previous notification, then `setColor()` sets both its background and accent colors.

Even when it succeeds at that, the notification stays colored when it reverts to a pull-down notification. So this approach doesn't work to even when it does correctly predict when the system will open a heads-up notification.

**Summary:** I'm seeking a workaround better than

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    builder.setColor(context.getColor(R.color.gray_text)); // #9e9e9e
}
```

in that it makes heads-up notifications more readable without risking making pull-down notifications hard to read or garish on any Marshmallow devices.

Answer (score 1):

The problem does not only arise for "compat" notifications. Just adding this line:

```
builder.setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle());
```

made my notification gray (with white text) in Android 6, while it remains white in Android 7. I do not have an Android 8 device for testing.

Note that I did not use some "compat" class here.

I suggest writing a bug report.

Comment: They fixed the bug in Android v7 and it remained fixed in v8. I could file a bug report hoping that a future NotificationCompat library might add a workaround for v6, but I'm not optimistic. A workaround there would most likely have fragile dependencies on the app's color choices, so it could make more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 1):

Things are even worse:

1.

I am using setSmallIcon() and setLargeIcon().

On Android 6 the small icon is only used in the menu bar, not in the notification itself. The notification uses the downscaled (in compact view) large icon which is displayed on the left side.

On Android 7 the large icon (downscaled in the compact view) is shown at the right side, well not the "right" side, but on the opposite of the left side, i.e. on the wrong side, to be precise. Further, the last line of the notification becomes the first one, which sabotages my use case. Further this line is preceded with the small icon and the app name; as a side effect the small line gets truncated which sabotages my app even more.

2.

On both Android versions setShowActionsInCompactView() did not have any visible effect.

3.

On lock screen the play/pause icon is visible (notification gets expanded), but not reachable without unlocking the device. So it's useless here.